How to access previous orders of a customer in Twig template in Shopware 6?
I am working on a Shopware 6 plugin and need to modify a Twig template to include conversion tracking parameters based on whether a customer has previous paid orders.
Specifically, I need to set the tsCategory parameter to 2 if the customer has previous paid orders, otherwise, it should be 1.
Here is the relevant part of my <plugin root>/src/Resources/views/storefront/page/checkout/finish/index.html.twig file:
{% block layout_head_javascript_tracking_swag_after_finish %}
        {% set tsCategory = 1 %}
        <script>
            {% for item in page.order.lineItems.elements %}
                {% if item.type == PRODUCT_LINE_ITEM_TYPE %}
                        var tsOrderID = "{{ page.order.orderNumber|escape('js') }}";
                        var tsCategory = "{{ tsCategory }}";
            {% endfor %}
        </script>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}

How can I access and check if a customer has previous paid orders in this Twig template?
Any guidance on how to achieve this in Shopware 6 would be greatly appreciated!

Why don't you put the logic to fetch this data in your controller? Twig isn't meant for these things

Create a new file called CheckoutFinishSubscriber.php in the <plugin root>/src/Subscriber/ directory.
File contents CheckoutFinishSubscriber.php:
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Swag\BasicExample\Subscriber;

use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Order\Aggregate\OrderTransaction\OrderTransactionStates;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepository;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Criteria;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Filter\EqualsFilter;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Filter\NotFilter;
use Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\SalesChannelContext;
use Shopware\Storefront\Page\Checkout\Finish\CheckoutFinishPageLoadedEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class CheckoutFinishSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        private readonly EntityRepository $orderRepository
    ) {}

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            CheckoutFinishPageLoadedEvent::class => 'onCheckoutFinish',
        ];
    }

    public function onCheckoutFinish(CheckoutFinishPageLoadedEvent $event): void
    {
        $salesChannelContext = $event->getSalesChannelContext();
        $page = $event->getPage();
        $currentOrderId = $page->getOrder()->getId();

        $paidOrderCount = $this->findPaidOrderCountByCustomer($currentOrderId, $salesChannelContext);
        $tsCategory = $paidOrderCount > 0 ? 2 : 1;

        $page->assign([
            'tsCategory' => $tsCategory
        ]);
    }

    private function findPaidOrderCountByCustomer(string $currentOrderId, SalesChannelContext $salesChannelContext): int
    {
        $criteria = new Criteria();
        $criteria->addFilter(new NotFilter(
            NotFilter::CONNECTION_AND,
            [new EqualsFilter('order.id', $currentOrderId)]
        ));
        $criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('order.salesChannelId', $salesChannelContext->getSalesChannelId()));
        $criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('order.orderCustomer.customerId', $salesChannelContext->getCustomer()->getId()));
        $criteria->addAssociation('transactions.stateMachineState');
        $criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('transactions.stateMachineState.name', OrderTransactionStates::STATE_PAID));

        return $this->orderRepository->search($criteria, $salesChannelContext->getContext())->getTotal();
    }
}

Register subscriber in the <plugin root>/src/Resources/config/services.xml file.
File contents services.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <services>
        <service id="Swag\BasicExample\Subscriber\CheckoutFinishSubscriber">
            <argument type="service" id="order.repository"/>
            <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber"/>
        </service>
    </services>
</container>

Now you can use the variable {% set tsCategory = page.tsCategory %} in the <plugin root>/src/Resources/views/storefront/page/checkout/finish/index.html.twig file.
Additional documentation that will help you:

Listening to Events
Finding Events
Using the State Machine


$lastTransaction->getStateMachineState() === null this returns true, even when i change the status of payment to Paid.

I modified the code a bit by adding filtering by transactions.stateMachineState.name.
